# port forwarding using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cpanel, whm, webmail

I want to forward the cpanel and webmail ports using .htaccess as follows:

www.mydomain.com:2082 -> www.sharedserver.com:2083

I tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.mydomain.com):2082$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.mydomain.com):2083$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.sharedserver.com:2083 [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^2082$
 RewriteRule .* https://www.sharedserver.com:2083 [L,R]
```

Check this for reference: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/ssl-example-usage-in-htaccess.html

Comment: The `%{SERVER_NAME}` is based on the `ServerName` directive of the vhost/host that is handling the request.

Answer (score 0):

The port isn't guaranteed to be part of the "Host:" request header. You can match against the `%{SERVER_PORT}` variable which is the port of the vhost/host that is handling the request:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^2082$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.sharedserver.com:2083/$1 [L,R=302]
```